# GraphQL on templateless page - It doesn't return data on firing query in GraphQL

Tags: sdl-tridion, sites-9.5, graphql, pca

I have 2 pages in SDL Tridion:

1. Template based page ( where page template is "Content Page" ) and
2. Templateless page (where page template is "Data Publishing page Template").

When I hit query in GraphQL for template based page, It returns JSON in *data* of *rawContent*

````
 ```{
      page(namespaceId: 1, publicationId: 5, pageId: xxx) {
        itemId
        title
        url
        rawContent {
          data
          id
          content
          charSet
        }
      }
    }
````

but the same query didn't work for templateless page, It returns **null** in *data* and *content* as **blank space**. Does anyone has clue about how to get JSON for templateless page?

Answer (score 6):

To fetch the As-is data template less publishing, called “untyped content” from GraphQL:

```
{
  page(namespaceId: 1, publicationId: 5, pageId: 730)  
  {
    itemId
    title
    url
    content {
      ... on UntypedContent
      {
        data
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Updated:**
In Sites 9.5 Templates Data-only publishing, and semantic content models (custom GraphQL Schema).

You have two approaches to consume your published data:

- As-is called “untyped content”
- By [defining custom semantic models](https://docs.sdl.com/816112/658699/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5/graphql-samples) that allow you to map JSON transformations to either change the structure of your content or retrieve only some fields of a JSON data fragment.

Useful references:

- [GraphQL samples](https://docs.sdl.com/816112/658699/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5/graphql-samples)
- [Customizing GraphQL querying in the Public Content API](https://docs.sdl.com/816112/757595/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5/customizing-graphql-querying-in-the-public-content-api)
- [Approaches to defining a custom GraphQL Schema](https://docs.sdl.com/816112/757655/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5/approaches-to-defining-a-custom-graphql-schema)
- [Why Sites 9.5 is the best release for the last 10 years](https://community.rws.com/product-groups/tridion/tridion-sites/b/blog-posts/posts/why-sites-9-5-is-the-best-release-for-last-10-years)
- [SDL Tridion Sites - Sites 9.5 Semantic Content Modeling (Video)](https://community.rws.com/product-groups/tridion/tridion-sites/b/blog-posts/posts/why-sites-9-5-is-the-best-release-for-last-10-years)

**Note:** AFAIK In Sites 9.6 release automatic semantic models generated based on schemas fields to query individual fields without the need to define custom semantic models.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Isn't there a way to get JSON of  templateless like template version? content returns type and id of the page only.

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: I will look around Semantic Content Modeling, Thank you for your help.!!

Comment: Where is this mentioned in the documentation, Velu?

Comment: @Quirijn, Updated my reference links correctly now, refer to the last link Why Sites 9.5 is the best release for the last 10 years, It was explained in the Data publishing and semantic content models section, The sample query page I couldn't find UntypedContent graphql query in the documentation. I did feedback already to the R&D and documentation team to update the same.

Comment: I've summarized the [three ways to get content from the CD API in this post](https://community.rws.com/product-groups/tridion/tridion-sites/b/techweblog/posts/three-ways-to-use-graphql-with-the-tridion-content-delivery-api-) on RWS Community.